# number with delimiter causes problem with sort in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, datatables

I have a table in RAILS that displays ok, and for showing more friendly I use number_to_currency or number_with_delimiter, this works ok but the table has the option to sort the columns (datatables.net) and when you sort the order is 111, 11, 1, 222, 22, 2, etc like a string, if I put .to_i I lose the format again and come back to a number like 32039480982435028 it´s unreadable. How to format an integer? and still been an integer

`<td><%= number_to_currency(trabajo.total, delimiter: ".", precision: 0) %></td>`

[image]

Comment: What's doing the sorting? Ruby or JavaScript?

Comment: JavaScript, https://datatables.net/

Comment: I don't use Datatables but it looks like you can use [`data-order` or `data-sort`](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html) attributes in the HTML or the [`sort`](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data) option if you're loading data through AJAX.